# What is the best way to make a handsome GUI for a Java software

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I created a website that acts as a software.
Now i'm trying to do the exact same thing with Java.
is there a way to draw some objects like "div" in html, that i can change x and y position (absolute), background-image, background-color, and put other object into it, [...] with Java ?
I tried this code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.accessibility.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/* 
 * LayeredPaneDemo.java requires
 * images/dukeWaveRed.gif. 
 */
public class Demo extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener{
    private String[] layerStrings = { "Yellow (0)", "Magenta (1)",
                                      "Cyan (2)",   "Red (3)",
                                      "Green (4)" };
    private Color[] layerColors = { Color.yellow, Color.magenta,
                                    Color.cyan,   Color.red,
                                    Color.green };

    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private JLabel dukeLabel;
    private JCheckBox onTop;
    private JComboBox layerList;

    //Action commands
    private static String ON_TOP_COMMAND = "ontop";
    private static String LAYER_COMMAND = "layer";

    //Adjustments to put Duke's toe at the cursor's tip.
    private static final int XFUDGE = 40;
    private static final int YFUDGE = 57;

    public Demo()    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        //Create and load the duke icon.
        final ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/dukeWaveRed.gif");

        //Create and set up the layered pane.
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                                    "Move the Mouse to Move Duke"));
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        //This is the origin of the first label added.
        Point origin = new Point(10, 20);

        //This is the offset for computing the origin for the next label.
        int offset = 35;

        //Add several overlapping, colored labels to the layered pane
        //using absolute positioning/sizing.
        for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[i], layerColors[i], origin);
            layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
           origin.x += offset;
            origin.y += offset;
        }

        //Create and add the Duke label to the layered pane.
       dukeLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        if (icon != null) {
            dukeLabel.setBounds(15, 225, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Duke icon not found; using black square instead.");
            dukeLabel.setBounds(15, 225, 30, 30);
            dukeLabel.setOpaque(true);
            dukeLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        layeredPane.add(dukeLabel, new Integer(2), 0);

        //Add control pane and layered pane to this JPanel.
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        add(createControlPanel());
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        add(layeredPane);
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Demo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Create and set up a colored label.
    private JLabel createColoredLabel(String text, Color color, Point origin) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setForeground(Color.black);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        label.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
        return label;
    }

    //Create the control pane for the top of the frame.
    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        onTop = new JCheckBox("Top Position in Layer");
        onTop.setSelected(true);
        onTop.setActionCommand(ON_TOP_COMMAND);
        onTop.addActionListener(this);

        layerList = new JComboBox(layerStrings);
        layerList.setSelectedIndex(2);    //cyan layer
        layerList.setActionCommand(LAYER_COMMAND);
        layerList.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.add(layerList);
        controls.add(onTop);
        controls.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose Duke's Layer and Position"));
        return controls;
    }

    //Make Duke follow the cursor.
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        dukeLabel.setLocation(e.getX()-XFUDGE, e.getY()-YFUDGE);
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {} //do nothing

    //Handle user interaction with the check box and combo box.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if (ON_TOP_COMMAND.equals(cmd)) {
            if (onTop.isSelected())
                layeredPane.moveToFront(dukeLabel);
            else
                layeredPane.moveToBack(dukeLabel);

        }
        else if (LAYER_COMMAND.equals(cmd)) {
            int position = onTop.isSelected() ? 0 : 1;
            layeredPane.setLayer(dukeLabel,layerList.getSelectedIndex(),position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new Demo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the result :
[image]
It looks to run, but I can not put JLabel into JLabel (will have i to create my own object ? with a JLabel and with sons ?
And finally when i put an `addMouseListener` to a JLabel , if an other JLabel  is above it, i can click it through the other :-/

Comment: Jave swing is considered the old way of doing a GUI in Java. JavaFX is the fancey new thing for java to make gui applications. Not much experience with it yet, but that what I saw so far, looks neat and clean.

Comment: Why don't you use a WebView and/or JavaFX instead of the old and ugly Swing?

Comment: @meskobalazs, thats because that's what my teachers learn to me ... I will try JavaFX, thx :D

Comment: Will i have to dl a .jar file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaFX with Java 8.

- It is a bit slower in development until learned. Due to lambdas and component complexity.
- The styling can be done with CSS.
- There are animated effects.

Comment: Thx, will i have to dl a .jar file ?

Comment: JavaFX is best developed with Java 8, so that is the main requirement. Then it works out-of-the box. Mind, if it is to have good points in school, swing is way easier. Try it first.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question targets Swing, I'll add a Swing-oriented answer anyway for the people who find this question and really must use Swing for any reason.

The trick is to use a fitting *look & feel* to do it for you in Swing.

[Swing tutorial documentation on the subject.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

That alone doesn't answer the question as this is about make it pretty and the default look & feel selections are not exactly all that great to look at / didn't stand the test of time. But there are also third party look & feels available for download, you're not necessarily limited to what is bundled with the runtime by default.

As an example, one can use [Insubstantial](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/) (formerly known as Substance) to pretty up Swing applications. It is too naive to think that you can just plop this look & feel into an existing program and make it look good in an instant, but when you design your application with one of these look & feels from the beginning, the application can look very slick indeed.

But one should really use Swing only when it is a must. Swing is an aging technology and whatever extensions were available for download for it in its glory days are slowly disappearing from the internet / no longer maintained. On top of that it is basically the difference between choosing a pre-designed look & feel or having flexibility to do styling yourself, which JavaFX allows you to do with quite some flexibility.